# How can I obtain a float value from a double, with mantissa?

Tags: c, embedded

I'm sorry if I can't explain correctly, but my english management is so bad.

Well, the question is: I have a double var, and I cast this var to float, because I need to send exclusively 4 bytes, not 8. This isn't work for me, so I decide to calculate the value directly from IEEE754 standard.

I have this code:

```
union DoubleNumberIEEE754{
    struct{
    uint64_t mantissa : 52;
    uint64_t exponent : 11;
    uint64_t sign : 1;
    }raw;
    double d;
    char c[8];
}dnumber;

floatval =  (pow((-1), dnumber.raw.sign) * (1 + dnumber.raw.mantissa) * pow(2, (dnumber.raw.exponent - 1023)));
```

With these code, I can't obtain the correct value.
I am watching the header  from linux to see the correct order of components, but I don't know if this code is correct.

Comment: Why doesn't casting to float work?

Comment: Definitely an XY problem.

Comment: I don't know, the cast just take the 4 MSB

Comment: @AraceliGuerrero Doing `(float) my_double` should cast it correctly. (And so should simply assigning it to a float.) Are you actually casting, as opposed to doing some type-punning/pointer-based thing?

Comment: @ThomasJager it's just what i did. But the cast doesn't work correctly, i don't know the reason(s).

Comment: @AraceliGuerrero Show a particular example that doesn't work for you, and how you determine that it's incorrect.

Comment: To send to which machine? Do both machines have the same endianess?

Comment: Then you should ask a question about why the cast does not work (and include your failed attempt) rather then try to solve that unsuccessfully then ask why that solution does not work - that _is_ an X-Y problem.  If `float floatval = (float)dnumber.d ;` does not work, then `dnumber.d` is not the value you intended in any case - which is entirely possible given the undefined and implementation defined behaviour that this union will exhibit.  How are you observing the result?  It may be a problem of endianness if produced on one architecture and observed on another.

Comment: @ThomasJager Okay, let me explain: I have a double variable named Latitude, in this I receive information from a GPS. My Lat (in bytes) begin with 0x40 0x34 0xB8... and the rest of the LSB. I cast like this: valueFloat = (float) valueDouble; and I consider that it does not work because the frame "cast" begin with 0x40 0x34 0xB8... and another byte variable.

Comment: @Frankie_C Yes, both have the same endianess

Comment: @Clifford I have a question explain my old problem, but in spanish, to explain better. And I don't find the correct way to do the cast, for this reason I opted for a make this question.

Comment: @AraceliGuerrero Show *actual* code, don't just explain it. The cast is valid. Do you know that the `double` contains the actual value you expect? If you `printf` it, is it the value you expect?

Comment: @AraceliGuerrero : I understand that - my point is that you should explain the original problem you were trying to solve.  The cast should work - show us the code to tried rather then the attempted over-complex solution.  Edit the question to fix it rather than adding mode comments.  I suggest that you do not inspect the bytes but the actual value - in a debugger of by `printf` for example.

Comment: Regarding _"Lat (in bytes) begin with 0x40 0x34 0xB8... "_ what was the original value in decimal?  You don't have to explain much - the code, the input, the actual output and the output you expected, and how you made the observation (because you might just be looking at the wrong thing or in the wrong way).

Comment: With the embedded tag, I can only imagine this is a problem if the system does not actually support floating point.

Answer (score 2):

I am skeptical that the double-to-float conversion is broken, but, assuming it is:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


//  Create a mask of n low bits, for n from 0 to 63.
#define Mask(n) (((uint64_t) 1 << (n)) - 1)


/*  This routine converts float values to double values:

        float and double must be IEEE-754 binary32 and binary64, respectively.

        The payloads of NaNs are not preserved, and only a quiet NaN is
        returned.

        The double is represented to the nearest value in float, with ties
        rounded to the float with the even low bit in the significand.

    We assume a standard C conversion from double to float is broken for
    unknown reasons but that a converstion from a representable uint32_t to a
    float works.
*/
static float ConvertDoubleToFloat(double x)
{
    //  Copy the double into a uint64_t so we can access its representation.
    uint64_t u;
    memcpy(&u, &x, sizeof u);

    //  Extract the fields from the representation of a double.
    int      SignCode        = u >> 63;
    int      ExponentCode    = u >> 52 & Mask(11);
    uint64_t SignificandCode = u       & Mask(52);

    /*  Convert the fields to their represented values.

            The sign code merely encodes - or +.

            The exponent code is biased by 1023 from the actual exponent.

            The significand code represents the portion of the significand
            after the radix point.  However, since there is some problem
            converting float to double, we will maintain it with an integer
            type, scaled by 2**52 from its represented value.

            The exponent code also represents the portion of the significand
            before the radix point -- 1 if the exponent is non-zero, 0 if the
            exponent is zero.  We include that in the significand, scaled by
            2**52.
    */
    float    Sign = SignCode ? -1 : +1;
    int      Exponent = ExponentCode - 1023;
    uint64_t ScaledSignificand =
        (ExponentCode ? ((uint64_t) 1 << 52) : 0) + SignificandCode;

    //  Handle NaNs and infinities.
    if (ExponentCode == Mask(11))
        return Sign * (SignificandCode == 0 ? INFINITY : NAN);

    /*  Round the significand:

            If Exponent < -150, all bits of the significand are below 1/2 ULP
            of the least positive float, so they round to zero.

            If -150 <= Exponent < -126, only bits of the significand
            corresponding to exponent -149 remain in the significand, so we
            shift accordingly and round the residue.

            Otherwise, the top 24 bits of the significand remain in the
            significand (except when there is overflow to infinity), so we
            shift accordingly and round the residue.

        Note that the scaling in the new significand is 2**23 instead of 2**52,
        since we are shifting it for the float format.
    */
    uint32_t NewScaledSignificand;
    if (Exponent < -150)
        NewScaledSignificand = 0;
    else
    {
        unsigned Shift = 53 - (Exponent < -126 ? Exponent - -150 : 24);

        NewScaledSignificand = ScaledSignificand >> Shift;

        //  Clamp the exponent for subnormals.
        if (Exponent < -126)
            Exponent = -126;

        //  Examine the residue being lost and round accordingly.
        uint64_t Residue = ScaledSignificand - ((uint64_t) NewScaledSignificand << Shift);
        uint64_t Half    = (uint64_t) 1 << Shift-1;

        //  If the residue is greater than 1/2 ULP, round up (in magnitude).
        if (Half < Residue)
            NewScaledSignificand += 1;

        /*  If the residue is 1/2 ULP, round 0.1 to 0 and 1.1 to 10.0 (these
            numerals are binary with "." marking the ULP position).
        */
        else if (Half == Residue)
            NewScaledSignificand += NewScaledSignificand & 1;

        /*  Otherwise, the residue is less than 1/2, and we have already
            rounded down, in the shift.
        */
    }

    //  Combine the components, including removing the significand scaling.
    return Sign * ldexpf(NewScaledSignificand, Exponent-23);
}


static void TestOneSign(double x)
{
    float Expected = x;
    float Observed = ConvertDoubleToFloat(x);

    if (Observed != Expected && !(isnan(Observed) && isnan(Expected)))
    {
        printf("Error, %a -> %a, but expected %a.\n",
            x, Observed, Expected);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


static void Test(double x)
{
    TestOneSign(+x);
    TestOneSign(-x);
}


int main(void)
{
    for (int e = -1024; e < 1024; ++e)
    {
        Test(ldexp(0x1.0p0, e));
        Test(ldexp(0x1.4p0, e));
        Test(ldexp(0x1.8p0, e));
        Test(ldexp(0x1.cp0, e));
        Test(ldexp(0x1.5555540p0, e));
        Test(ldexp(0x1.5555548p0, e));
        Test(ldexp(0x1.5555550p0, e));
        Test(ldexp(0x1.5555558p0, e));
        Test(ldexp(0x1.5555560p0, e));
        Test(ldexp(0x1.5555568p0, e));
        Test(ldexp(0x1.5555570p0, e));
        Test(ldexp(0x1.5555578p0, e));
    }
    Test(3.14);
    Test(0);
    Test(INFINITY);
    Test(NAN);
    Test(1/3.);
    Test(0x1p128);
    Test(0x1p128 - 0x1p104);
    Test(0x1p128 - 0x.9p104);
    Test(0x1p128 - 0x.8p104);
    Test(0x1p128 - 0x.7p104);
}
```

Comment: I love how this answer actually shows how floating point numbers are implemented. Wikipedia has a nice table of the formats for various precision floating point numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats